# Cake PHP 1.3 – New app, not able to connect to DB, php_network_getaddresses / nodename nor servname provided

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm new to PHP, have a solid foundation in Ruby, just trying to get a Cake PHP app up and running. I'm using an older version – version 1.3 – for professional reasons. Upgrading unfortunately isn't an option to solve this.

That said, I'd love some help getting my db all set up.

My error:

`Warning (2): mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 561]`

The stacktrace:

```
mysql_connect - [internal], line ??
DboMysql::connect() - CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php, line 561
DboSource::__construct() - CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 143
ConnectionManager::getDataSource() - CORE/cake/libs/model/connection_manager.php, line 114
include - APP/views/pages/home.ctp, line 77
View::_render() - CORE/cake/libs/view/view.php, line 736
View::render() - CORE/cake/libs/view/view.php, line 431
Controller::render() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 909
PagesController::display() - CORE/cake/libs/controller/pages_controller.php, line 83
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 86
```

Lines 82-87 from `app/webroot/index.php`:

```
if (isset($_GET['url']) && $_GET['url'] === 'favicon.ico') {
        return;
    } else {
        $Dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
        $Dispatcher->dispatch(); /* line 86 */
    }
```

If needed, my `database.php` file looks like this:

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    var $default = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'dumpbox_host',
        'port' => 8889,
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'my_test_db',
    );
}
?>
```

I've looked at a number of solutions for this, most seem related to later versions of Cake PHP. Any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `dumpbox_host` a valid MySQL hostname that your server can resolve? I.e. if you were to connect manually from the command line e.g. `mysql -h'dumpbox_host' -u'root' -p'password' 'my_test_db'` does it work?

Comment: Why build a new app on 1.3?  Cake is now on 3.0.  If nothing else, at least go 2.x.  It's very similar code.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not able to resolve your database's hostname "**dumpbox_host**". If your database is hosted locally, just use "**localhost**".

If your server is a flavor of linux, edit **/etc/hosts** and add the proper IP for "dumpbox_host". Otherwise, you can change the hostname directly to something you know works.

If you're on Windows, you can add names to **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**